# Upgrade to Angular 13 : Error - NGCC failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I just upgraded to Angular 13 from v8. (All my angular dependencies set to 13.0.2) (Updated my node version to 12.20.2). When I try to ng serve, I get the following NGCC failed error

```
Error: Error on worker #1: TypeError: ts24.isNamedTupleMember is not a function
    at StaticInterpreter.visitType (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:3340:21)
    at StaticInterpreter.visitVariableDeclaration (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:3027:36)
    at StaticInterpreter.visitDeclaration (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:3006:19)
    at StaticInterpreter.visitAmbiguousDeclaration (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:3085:165)
    at StaticInterpreter.visitIdentifier (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:2989:25)
    at StaticInterpreter.visitExpression (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:2882:21)
    at StaticInterpreter.visitObjectLiteralExpression (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:2934:28)
    at StaticInterpreter.visitExpression (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:2880:21)
    at StaticInterpreter.visitArrayLiteralExpression (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:2920:25)
    at StaticInterpreter.visitExpression (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:2894:21)
    at ClusterMaster.onWorkerMessage (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/main-ngcc.js:5139:15)
    at file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/main-ngcc.js:5049:72
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/main-ngcc.js:5207:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (internal/cluster/master.js:174:13)
    at Worker.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (internal/cluster/worker.js:32:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:877:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
(node:25668) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: NGCC failed.
    at NgccProcessor.process (/Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:146:19)
    at /Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/plugin.js:141:27
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (/Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1054:30)
    at /Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1099:29
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:18:1)
(node:25668) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25668) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...(node:25746) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPIPE
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:807:20)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:678:19)
    at file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:13756:13
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at sendMessageToMaster (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:13752:10)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:13817:17)
    at Worker.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at process.<anonymous> (internal/cluster/worker.js:32:12)
    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:877:12)
(node:25746) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25746) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
⠏ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...(node:25741) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPIPE
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:807:20)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:678:19)
    at file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:13756:13
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at sendMessageToMaster (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:13752:10)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (file:///Users/k28483/Documents/WORK/MAP/periscope/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/ngcc_cluster_worker.js:13817:17)
    at Worker.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at process.<anonymous> (internal/cluster/worker.js:32:12)
    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:877:12)
(node:25741) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

I tried adding enableIvy : false in ts.config.json as follows, removed node moduled and reinstalled them. I still get the same error How do I fix this?

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

Comment: Maybe this: "**_Warning: We do not support migrating across multiple major versions at once. Please migrate each major version individually._**" from [here](https://update.angular.io/?v=8.0-13.0)?

Comment: Gradually working up the upgrade versions. Thanks @RandyCasburn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent 2 days and finally got the issue fixed. Here are the steps that I followed.

```
1. Delete your package-lock.json
2. npm install --force
3. npm update --force
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error:

> Unknown arguments: use-program-dependencies, useProgramDependencies An
> unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed. See
> "C:...\angular-errors.log" for further details.

I just updated Angular Cli, material and Core, and other modules needed to my project, then updated npm and typescript package, and that’s all.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
npm update @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Comment: I tried this, and I still get the exact same error

Comment: @SaiKrishna Was your issue resolved? If yes, how?

Comment: @KartikWatwani, As suggested by Randy Casburn above, I took the approach of upgrading step by step to a higher version, following this : https://update.angular.io/?v=8.0-13.0

Answer (score 0):

Update the angular to the latest version will solve the issue
as my previous angular version was 13.2.1 and after updating it becomes 13.3.1